# Java swing sound playback ends prematurely

Tags: java, swing, audio, javasound

Within a Java swing application, the following snippet is supposed to play a siren. It starts OK but stops prematurely, not always at the same time (i.e. sometimes it stops almost immediately and sometimes after a longer delay, but usually it does not finish playing the whole sound file). What could be causing this?

I've done my best to create a minimal example that still has the problem:

```
package monster;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Example_2 extends JPanel {

    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Example_2() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        setBackground(Color.white);
        createPanel();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example_2 e = new Example_2();
        JFrame f    = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        f.add(e, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        new Thread(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        File f = new File("sound/siren_short.wav");
                        String url = "file:///"+f.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("\\\\","/").replaceAll(" ", "%20");
                        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(new Media(url));
                        mp.play();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
    }

    public static JFXPanel createPanel() {
        return new JFXPanel();
    }

}
```

Comment: The jvm is likely putting your media thread to sleep before it's done because it has something more important to do.  I'm hoping it's solving world hunger...  Have you tried running this in a debugger to see what thread your application is switching to?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: Does the entire Swing application close? Or does it continue to run while the sound file stops playing? Also, is your new thread a daemon or not?

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: @Phil Freihofner, the application continues to run without any other problems. The term daemon is new to me but I am hoping the answer to your question about this will be clear from the more complete example I've added.

Comment: `MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer(new Media(url));` Rather than mix Java-FX components in there, I would recommend trying this with the [`javax.sound.sampled.Clip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Clip.html).  There is an example on the [Java Sound info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

Comment: @ Foosh I have to humbly admit that I could not figure out how to do what you recommended. I managed to see the list of open threads in the debugger but couldn't figure out how to identify which thread the application is switching to at any given moment. Do you happen to have a reference for learning to use the (Eclipse) debugger for this type of thing?

Comment: @ Andrew Thompson, this fixed my problem, if you turn it into an answer I'll make it the accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the current example code "Example2" posted, it looks to me like the main() executes and exits. Yes, the call to MediaPlayer launches a background thread, but I'm guessing when the main() ends, this terminates the MediaPlayer thread as well (perhaps because it only has daemon status). I haven't used the MediaPlayer yet, myself, so I don't know if this behavior can result or not.

Here is a simple test for you: add the following line.

```
Thread.sleep(5000); // pauses 5 seconds
```

or something similar to the end of the main(), after the repaint() call. The number is milliseconds: use a number that is longer than the length of your sound. Does the sound now play to completion? You'll probably have to put the new line of code in a *try...catch* block.

Check out the api for Thread() when you get a chance. When you get to the page, I'd recommend doing a search on "daemon". There are methods for testing or setting daemon status, plus a terse explanation of what the status means. There is a chance that if you set your runnable to *not* be a daemon, the program (as shown) will play once and then hang with no way to terminate it except killing it via Eclipse (if it was run in Eclipse) or via an OS task manager.

I haven't delved much into debugging threads in Eclipse--am afraid I can't offer any suggestions there.

Andrew Thompson made a good suggestion, to make use of **Clip**. This has the benefit of keeping us in "familiar" territory. I've used **Clip** frequently, but not JavaFX libraries. If you *had* used **Clip**, the line of code I'm suggesting (Thread.sleep) would definitely have been needed to allow the sound to play to completion.

Here is a theory: the code which loads and executes the play() command is non-daemon. However, the background processes which deliver the sound data to the line are daemon. If that were the case, then the behavior I describe (termination after the main thread is done) would be consistent.

Comment: The problem persisted after adding Thread.sleep. However, using Clip fixed it. I found http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info very useful for figuring out how to use Clip. Thank you!

Comment: Agreed, if he makes it into an answer I'll accept it (there's no way I can do that without him making it into an answer, right?).